# when edit the page richhtmlfield styels are not loading in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

In Publishing Layouts richhtmlfield control  styels are not loading in sharepoint 2013 when i edit the page.If i remove the PrefixStyleSheet property it could be loading the styles  properly.Do we have any  improments of this control in sharepoint 2010 and 2013.Hope any one can help me why its not loading in 2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty much the same as SharePoint 2010. These are the steps that can help you.

- Create a custom css (custom-rte.css) file and publish it within Style Library of the site collection.
- Prefix style sheet:

  <PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField FieldName="PublishingPageContent" HasInitialFocus="True" MinimumEditHeight="300px" runat="server" PrefixStyleSheet="custom-rte" />
- Use Cssregistration to add the css inside PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead of your page layout/master page.

  <SharePointWebControls:CssRegistration name="<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style Library/custom-rte.css %>" runat="server" />
- Sample CSS code:

  ```
  /* Custom RTE */
  H1.custom-rteElement-H1
  {
      -ms-name:"My Custom Heading";
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      color: red;
      font-size: 18px;
      font-weight: normal;
  }
  H1.custom-rteElement-H1B
  {
      -ms-name:"My Custom Heading H1B";
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  }
  .custom-rteStyle-Normal {
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
      color: inherit;
      font-family: inherit;
      font-size: 12px;
      font-weight: normal;
  }
  .custom-rteElement-H1, .ms-rtestate-field H1.custom-rteElement-H1, .custom-rteElement-H1B, .ms-rtestate-field H1.custom-rteElement-H1B
  {
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      color: red;
      font-size: 18px;
      font-weight: normal;
  }
  /* @end */
  ```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your Replay,For me sharepoint 2010 it has been worked fine ,But After migrateing from 2010 to 2013 The rich html field control not loading the styles properly when i am edi the page,I tried the many times what ever your given the suggestion.But i am facing the same issue

Comment: There may be other css overriding your custom css. Can you post your css? The above screenshot was taken from SharePoint 2013

Comment: /* Custom Styles for Rich HTML Field */

nok-rteElement-H1 
{
  -ms-name:"Nokia Heading 1";
}

nok-rteElement-P
{
  -ms-name:"Nokia Text P";
}

nok-rteStyle-P
{
  -ms-name:"Nokia Text P";
}

/* End of Custom Styles for Rich HTML Field */
Here is my custom css for rich html field

Comment: Prefix Style sheet <PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField id="RichHtmlField1" runat="server" FieldName="PublishingPageContent" HasInitialFocus="True" MinimumEditHeight="300px" PrefixStyleSheet="nok-rte"/>

Comment: CssRegistration :<SharePointWebControls:CssRegistration name="Nokia.BSP/NokiaDefaultStylesEdit.css" After="Nokia.BSP/NokiaCoreStyles.css" runat="server"/>       this is my code

Comment: Please try the edited CSS. 
For CssRegistration shouldn't there be "_layouts/" before Nokia.BSP/Nokia....css ?
If you can see your css loaded into Firebug/IE Developer toolbar, CSSRegistration should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've edited your css a litte. Please try this:

```
/* Custom RTE */
    H1.nok-rteElement-H1 {
        -ms-name:"Nokia Heading 1";
    }
    P.nok-rteElement-P {
        -ms-name:"Nokia Text P";
    }
    P.nok-rteStyle-P { 
        -ms-name:"Nokia Text P"; 
    } 
    .nok-rteElement-H1, .ms-rtestate-field H1.nok-rteElement-H1 {
        /* Define your css for H1 here */
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif; /* Define your css here */
        color: red;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: normal;
    }
    .nok-rteElement-P, .ms-rtestate-field P.nok-rteElement-P {
        /* Define your css for P here */
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif; /* Define your css here */
        color: #000;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: normal;
        line-height: 18px;
        margin: 5px 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
/* @end */
```

Comment: Hi Aveenav thanks for your replay ,But i am not sure why i am facing the same issue.I tried with your updates and i could add the _layouts/before nokia.bsp,please check the below updated my css registration :     <SharePointWebControls:CssRegistration name="/_layouts/15/Nokia.BSP/NokiaDefaultStylesEdit.css" After="/_layouts/15/Nokia.BSP/NokiaCoreStyles.css"> runat="server"/>

Comment: You have an extra '/' after ="/_layouts/15/Nokia.BSP/NokiaCoreStyles.css">

<SharePointWebControls:CssRegistration name="/_layouts/15/Nokia.BSP/NokiaDefaultStylesEdit.css" After="/_layouts/15/Nokia.BSP/NokiaCoreStyles.css" runat="server" />

Comment: <SharePointWebControls:CssRegistration name="Nokia.BSP/NokiaDefaultStylesEdit.css" After="Nokia.BSP/NokiaCoreStyles.css" runat="server"/> this is what i am using  for cssRegistration .Could you please consider this.Still i am facing the same issue Aveenav below i am shareing the Hichhtmlfield tag.                   <PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField id="RichHtmlField1" runat="server" FieldName="PublishingPageContent" HasInitialFocus="True" MinimumEditHeight="300px" PrefixStyleSheet="nok-rte"/>

Comment: IF i remove the prefixStyleSheet property ,It was loading the RichHtmlField styles,With out the property how it was loading the styles.

Comment: Where have you deployed your Nokida.BSP folder? 

Can you try adding the folder within Style Libaray
<SharePointWebControls:CssRegistration name="<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style Library/NokiaBSP/nokiacorestyles.css %>" runat="server" />